# Cakefile build task error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, build-automation, cakefile

I am trying to build the code given as TODO example in spine framework. I have installed coffescript using npm, and cake builder is included to it.

When I navigate to Cakefile dir, and execute `cake build` I get the following error:

> src/local.coffee:1:1: error: the variable "Spine" can't be assigned
>   with ?= because it has not been declared before Spine ?=
>   require('spine') ^^^^^

The cake file im trying to run is the default coming with the example, and is in the same dir as the git copy https://github.com/maccman/spine.todos .

I did search online but could not find reports of this issue, or how I can solve it. This error has appeared on other cases (https://github.com/maccman/spine.contacts/pull/14) but solution cannot be applied to TODO example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example was written with an older version of coffeescript.
The behaviour of `?=` has changed since then. See this [issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2605) for more details.

Commenting out this line (the first one in src/local.coffee) seems to get it working again.